# How to dynamically layout atoms in atomic orbitals given a certain set of desired layouts?

Tags: algorithm, layout

I am laying this out as a square:

[image]

Typically you see it it in a circle, which is easy you just distribute the electrons evenly.

[image]

But in my square case, the outer interior of each square I want to put small squares to layout the electrons according to the [Electron shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell#Subshells). I want to do this somewhat dynamically without having to write out each of the 118 atom cases manually.

The desired layouts are like this if there are 8 electrons in a shell:

```
x x x
x   x
x x x
```

If there are only 7, it should be like this:

```
x x x
x   x
x   x
```

Then these cases:

```
6:
x - x
x   x
x - x

5:
- x - 
x   x
x - x

4:
- x -
x   x
- x -

3:
- x -
-   -
x - x

2:
- - -
x   x
- - -

1:
- x -
-   -
- - -
```

Then the 18 case is:

```
 x x x x x 
x         x
x         x
x         x
x         x
 x x x x x

 x x - x x 
x         x
x         x
x         x
x         x
 x x x x x

 x x - x x 
x         x
x         x
x         x
x         x
 x x - x x

 x - x - x 
x         x
x         x
x         x
x         x
 x x - x x

 x - x - x 
x         x
x         x
x         x
x         x
 x - x - x
```

I don't have a super-hard-fast desire to layout each configuration in a specific way (even though I started by showing specific configurations). I am mainly looking to figure out some sort of *pattern* or sort of equation to lay them out in a semi-nice/decent way. How can it be done?

The electron shells are like this:

```
const SHELLS = `Hydrogen,1
Helium,2
Lithium,2:1
Beryllium,2:2
Boron,2:3
Carbon,2:4
Nitrogen,2:5
Oxygen,2:6
Fluorine,2:7
Neon,2:8
Sodium,2:8:1
Magnesium,2:8:2
Aluminium,2:8:3
Silicon,2:8:4
Phosphorus,2:8:5
Sulfur,2:8:6
Chlorine,2:8:7
Argon,2:8:8
Potassium,2:8:8:1
Calcium,2:8:8:2
Scandium,2:8:9:2
Titanium,2:8:10:2
Vanadium,2:8:11:2
Chromium,2:8:13:1
Manganese,2:8:13:2
Iron,2:8:14:2
Cobalt,2:8:15:2
Nickel,2:8:16:2
Copper,2:8:18:1
Zinc,2:8:18:2
Gallium,2:8:18:3
Germanium,2:8:18:4
Arsenic,2:8:18:5
Selenium,2:8:18:6
Bromine,2:8:18:7
Krypton,2:8:18:8
Rubidium,2:8:18:8:1
Strontium,2:8:18:8:2
Yttrium,2:8:18:9:2
Zirconium,2:8:18:10:2
Niobium,2:8:18:12:1
Molybdenum,2:8:18:13:1
Technetium,2:8:18:13:2
Ruthenium,2:8:18:15:1
Rhodium,2:8:18:16:1
Palladium,2:8:18:18
Silver,2:8:18:18:1
Cadmium,2:8:18:18:2
Indium,2:8:18:18:3
Tin,2:8:18:18:4
Antimony,2:8:18:18:5
Tellurium,2:8:18:18:6
Iodine,2:8:18:18:7
Xenon,2:8:18:18:8
Caesium,2:8:18:18:8:1
Barium,2:8:18:18:8:2
Lanthanum,2:8:18:18:9:2
Cerium,2:8:18:19:9:2
Praseodymium,2:8:18:21:8:2
Neodymium,2:8:18:22:8:2
Promethium,2:8:18:23:8:2
Samarium,2:8:18:24:8:2
Europium,2:8:18:25:8:2
Gadolinium,2:8:18:25:9:2
Terbium,2:8:18:27:8:2
Dysprosium,2:8:18:28:8:2
Holmium,2:8:18:29:8:2
Erbium,2:8:18:30:8:2
Thulium,2:8:18:31:8:2
Ytterbium,2:8:18:32:8:2
Lutetium,2:8:18:32:9:2
Hafnium,2:8:18:32:10:2
Tantalum,2:8:18:32:11:2
Tungsten,2:8:18:32:12:2
Rhenium,2:8:18:32:13:2
Osmium,2:8:18:32:14:2
Iridium,2:8:18:32:15:2
Platinum,2:8:18:32:17:1
Gold,2:8:18:32:18:1
Mercury,2:8:18:32:18:2
Thallium,2:8:18:32:18:3
Lead,2:8:18:32:18:4
Bismuth,2:8:18:32:18:5
Polonium,2:8:18:32:18:6
Astatine,2:8:18:32:18:7
Radon,2:8:18:32:18:8
Francium,2:8:18:32:18:8:1
Radium,2:8:18:32:18:8:2
Actinium,2:8:18:32:18:9:2
Thorium,2:8:18:32:18:10:2
Protactinium,2:8:18:32:20:2
Uranium,2:8:18:32:21:9:2
Neptunium,2:8:18:32:22:9:2
Plutonium,2:8:18:32:24:8:2
Americium,2:8:18:32:25:8:2
Curium,2:8:18:32:25:9:2
Berkelium,2:8:18:32:27:8:2
Californium,2:8:18:32:28:8:2
Einsteinium,2:8:18:32:29:8:2
Fermium,2:8:18:32:30:8:2
Mendelevium,2:8:18:32:31:8:2
Nobelium,2:8:18:32:32:8:2
Lawrencium,2:8:18:32:32:8:3
Rutherfordium,2:8:18:32:32:10:2
Dubnium,2:8:18:32:32:11:2
Seaborgium,2:8:18:32:32:12:2
Bohrium,2:8:18:32:32:13:2
Hassium,2:8:18:32:32:14:2
Meitnerium,2:8:18:32:32:15:2
Darmstadtium,2:8:18:32:32:16:2
Roentgenium,2:8:18:32:32:17:2
Copernicium,2:8:18:32:32:18:2
Nihonium,2:8:18:32:32:18:3
Flerovium,2:8:18:32:32:18:4
Moscovium,2:8:18:32:32:18:5
Livermorium,2:8:18:32:32:18:6
Tennessine,2:8:18:32:32:18:7
Oganesson,2:8:18:32:32:18:8`
  .trim()
  .split('\n')
  .map(x => {
    const [a, b] = x.split(',')
    const c = b.split(':').map(x => parseInt(x, 10))
    return { name: a, shells: c }
  })
```

Is it possible do you think to come up with a simple algorithm for this, or must it be hardcoded?

Some constraints:

- The shells have 2, 8, 18, 32, 32 electrons.
- The electrons should go into preexisting slots, so there are only 8 slots for the 8, 18 for the 18, etc.. That is, you can't evenly distribute them around the edge.
- Other than that, the general layout should feel somewhat "balanced" (even though that is a fuzzy concept). So if there is just 17, it should take out one from the middle vertically. If there are only 3, it should make them into a triangle sort of thing. I don't see a way out of defining this manually, but I am sure there is a way to do it with some clever perspective.
- There might be multiple equally "balanced" ways of creating a layout, so it doesn't matter to me exactly which one is chosen.

It can be simulated just laying out `x` and `-` in a monospaced font, so don't need to full Next.js/React/SVG system that I am dealing with currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am stumped.

Comment: I would use [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: To place k electrons in a layer of size n, what about: (1) Number the spots from 0 to n-1; (2) Number the electrons from 0 to k-1; (3) For j in 0..k-1, place electron j at spot `floor(j * n / k)`

Comment: You only want to display the outer used shell, or every shell? If every shell, then where do the inner two "x" go in your first examples? And how would then the 8-shell fit in the 18-shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first solve the problem without any actual rendering considerations, but see the orbits as 1-dimensional arrays of bits -- let's say a string of "x" and "-". The inner orbit could have three possibilities:

```
"--"
"x-"
"xx"
```

The next orbit would have these:

```
"--------",
"x-------",
"x---x---",
"x--x-x--",
"x-x-x-x-",
"x-xx-xx-",
"-xxx-xxx",
"xxxx-xxx",
"xxxxxxxx"
```

To distribute the "x" evenly you would step with fractions of the string length over the desired number of "x". To avoid irregular shapes, you could mirror positions as soon as you find them, and stop generating more when together with the mirrored positions you have them all.

Once you have generated all these bit patterns, we can focus on the format of the squares layout. For that you could define a multiline string that is a template for how you generally want to render it, using specific placeholders for where you want the electron slots to be. So "a" in that string would depict a slot in the inner orbit, "b" in the second one, ...etc. For instance:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                         g                         │
│   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐   │
│   │     f       f       f       f       f     │   │
│   │   ┌───────────────────────────────────┐   │   │
│ g │ f │ e   e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e   e │ f │ g │
│   │   │   ┌───────────────────────────┐   │   │   │
│   │   │   │     d d d d d d d d d     │   │   │   │
│   │   │ e │ d ┌───────────────────┐ d │ e │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │   c  c  c  c  c   │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   ┌───────────┐   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │ f │ e │   │ c │     b     │ c │   │ e │ f │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   │ b ┌───┐ b │   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │ c │   │ a │   │ c │   │   │   │   │
│ g │   │ e │ d │   │ b │   │ b │   │ d │ e │   │ g │
│   │   │   │   │ c │   │ a │   │ c │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   │ b └───┘ b │   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │ f │ e │   │ c │     b     │ c │   │ e │ f │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   └───────────┘   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │   c  c  c  c  c   │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │ e │ d └───────────────────┘ d │ e │   │   │
│   │   │   │     d d d d d d d d d     │   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───────────────────────────┘   │   │   │
│ g │ f │ e   e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e   e │ f │ g │
│   │   └───────────────────────────────────┘   │   │
│   │     f       f       f       f       f     │   │
│   └───────────────────────────────────────────┘   │
│                         g                         │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I just had some fun with those box drawing characters, but you can of course use an entirely different string. The only requirement is that there are two "a" characters in it, 8 "b", 18 "c", ...etc. All the other characters can be anything.

A little function can find the positions of the slots in the orbits and then use the bit patterns to place the desired character ("x" or "-") at the appropriate slot.

Here is an interactive implementation of that idea:

```js
const templateInput = `
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                         g                         │
│   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐   │
│   │     f       f       f       f       f     │   │
│   │   ┌───────────────────────────────────┐   │   │
│ g │ f │ e   e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e   e │ f │ g │
│   │   │   ┌───────────────────────────┐   │   │   │
│   │   │   │     d d d d d d d d d     │   │   │   │
│   │   │ e │ d ┌───────────────────┐ d │ e │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │   c  c  c  c  c   │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   ┌───────────┐   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │ f │ e │   │ c │     b     │ c │   │ e │ f │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   │ b ┌───┐ b │   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │ c │   │ a │   │ c │   │   │   │   │
│ g │   │ e │ d │   │ b │   │ b │   │ d │ e │   │ g │
│   │   │   │   │ c │   │ a │   │ c │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   │ b └───┘ b │   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │ f │ e │   │ c │     b     │ c │   │ e │ f │   │
│   │   │   │ d │   └───────────┘   │ d │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │   c  c  c  c  c   │   │   │   │   │
│   │   │ e │ d └───────────────────┘ d │ e │   │   │
│   │   │   │     d d d d d d d d d     │   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───────────────────────────┘   │   │   │
│ g │ f │ e   e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e  e   e │ f │ g │
│   │   └───────────────────────────────────┘   │   │
│   │     f       f       f       f       f     │   │
│   └───────────────────────────────────────────┘   │
│                         g                         │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
`.trim();

function parseTemplate(template) {
    function shellPattern(length, count) {
        const arr = [];
        const even = 1 - count % 2;
        const symbols = count > length >> 1 && count < length ? "x-" : "-x";
        count = symbols[0] == "x" ? length - count : count;
        for (let j = 0, step = 0; true; j++) {
            const surpass = +((j + 0.5) * count >= step);
            const symbol = symbols[surpass];
            if (surpass) step += length;
            arr[j] = symbol;
            if (j) { // Mirror left-right
                if (length - j <= j) break;
                arr[length - j] = symbol;
            }
            if (even) { // Mirror top-bottom
                if ((length >> 1) - j <= j) break;
                arr[(length >> 1) + j] = arr[(length >> 1) - j] = symbol;
            }
        }
        const pat = arr.join("");
        // Turn 180° if top cell is not occupied:
        return pat[0] == "-" ? pat.slice(length >> 1) + pat.slice(0, length >> 1) : pat;
    }
    return {
        shells: Array.from("abcdefg", ch => {
            const forward = [];
            const backward = [];
            let i = 0;
            template.split(/^/gm).forEach((line, y, {length}) => {
                const hits = Array.from(line.matchAll(ch), ({index}) => i + index);
                if (y * 2 < length) {
                    backward.push(...hits.slice(0, hits.length >> 1).reverse());
                    forward.push(...hits.slice(hits.length >> 1));
                } else {
                    backward.push(...hits.slice(0, hits.length >> 1));
                    forward.push(...hits.slice(hits.length >> 1).reverse());
                }
                i += line.length;
            });
            const indices = forward.concat(backward.reverse());
            return {
                indices,
                patterns: ['-'.repeat(indices.length), 
                           ...indices.map((_, count) => shellPattern(indices.length, count+1))]
            }
        }),
        template: template.replace(/[a-g]/g, ".")
    };
}

function toGrid(model, element) {
    const shells = element?.match(/\d+/g)?.map(Number) ?? [];
    const arr = [...model.template];
    shells.forEach((count, shellNum) => {
        const {patterns, indices} = model.shells[shellNum];
        Array.from(patterns[count], (ch, i) => arr[indices[i]] = ch);
    });
    return arr.join("");
}

const model = parseTemplate(templateInput);

// I/O handling

const input = document.querySelector("select");
input.onchange = () =>
    document.querySelector("pre").textContent = toGrid(model, input.value);
input.onchange();
```

```css
pre { font-size: 8px; display: inline-block; width = 50hv; float: left }
```

```html
<pre></pre>
<select multiple size="15">
<option>Hydrogen,1
<option>Helium,2
<option>Lithium,2:1
<option>Beryllium,2:2
<option>Boron,2:3
<option>Carbon,2:4
<option>Nitrogen,2:5
<option>Oxygen,2:6
<option>Fluorine,2:7
<option>Neon,2:8
<option>Sodium,2:8:1
<option>Magnesium,2:8:2
<option>Aluminium,2:8:3
<option>Silicon,2:8:4
<option>Phosphorus,2:8:5
<option>Sulfur,2:8:6
<option>Chlorine,2:8:7
<option>Argon,2:8:8
<option>Potassium,2:8:8:1
<option>Calcium,2:8:8:2
<option>Scandium,2:8:9:2
<option>Titanium,2:8:10:2
<option>Vanadium,2:8:11:2
<option>Chromium,2:8:13:1
<option>Manganese,2:8:13:2
<option>Iron,2:8:14:2
<option>Cobalt,2:8:15:2
<option>Nickel,2:8:16:2
<option>Copper,2:8:18:1
<option>Zinc,2:8:18:2
<option>Gallium,2:8:18:3
<option>Germanium,2:8:18:4
<option>Arsenic,2:8:18:5
<option>Selenium,2:8:18:6
<option>Bromine,2:8:18:7
<option>Krypton,2:8:18:8
<option>Rubidium,2:8:18:8:1
<option>Strontium,2:8:18:8:2
<option>Yttrium,2:8:18:9:2
<option>Zirconium,2:8:18:10:2
<option>Niobium,2:8:18:12:1
<option>Molybdenum,2:8:18:13:1
<option>Technetium,2:8:18:13:2
<option>Ruthenium,2:8:18:15:1
<option>Rhodium,2:8:18:16:1
<option>Palladium,2:8:18:18
<option>Silver,2:8:18:18:1
<option>Cadmium,2:8:18:18:2
<option>Indium,2:8:18:18:3
<option>Tin,2:8:18:18:4
<option>Antimony,2:8:18:18:5
<option>Tellurium,2:8:18:18:6
<option>Iodine,2:8:18:18:7
<option>Xenon,2:8:18:18:8
<option>Caesium,2:8:18:18:8:1
<option>Barium,2:8:18:18:8:2
<option>Lanthanum,2:8:18:18:9:2
<option>Cerium,2:8:18:19:9:2
<option>Praseodymium,2:8:18:21:8:2
<option>Neodymium,2:8:18:22:8:2
<option>Promethium,2:8:18:23:8:2
<option>Samarium,2:8:18:24:8:2
<option>Europium,2:8:18:25:8:2
<option>Gadolinium,2:8:18:25:9:2
<option>Terbium,2:8:18:27:8:2
<option>Dysprosium,2:8:18:28:8:2
<option>Holmium,2:8:18:29:8:2
<option>Erbium,2:8:18:30:8:2
<option>Thulium,2:8:18:31:8:2
<option>Ytterbium,2:8:18:32:8:2
<option>Lutetium,2:8:18:32:9:2
<option>Hafnium,2:8:18:32:10:2
<option>Tantalum,2:8:18:32:11:2
<option>Tungsten,2:8:18:32:12:2
<option>Rhenium,2:8:18:32:13:2
<option>Osmium,2:8:18:32:14:2
<option>Iridium,2:8:18:32:15:2
<option>Platinum,2:8:18:32:17:1
<option>Gold,2:8:18:32:18:1
<option>Mercury,2:8:18:32:18:2
<option>Thallium,2:8:18:32:18:3
<option>Lead,2:8:18:32:18:4
<option>Bismuth,2:8:18:32:18:5
<option>Polonium,2:8:18:32:18:6
<option>Astatine,2:8:18:32:18:7
<option>Radon,2:8:18:32:18:8
<option>Francium,2:8:18:32:18:8:1
<option>Radium,2:8:18:32:18:8:2
<option>Actinium,2:8:18:32:18:9:2
<option>Thorium,2:8:18:32:18:10:2
<option>Protactinium,2:8:18:32:20:2
<option>Uranium,2:8:18:32:21:9:2
<option>Neptunium,2:8:18:32:22:9:2
<option>Plutonium,2:8:18:32:24:8:2
<option>Americium,2:8:18:32:25:8:2
<option>Curium,2:8:18:32:25:9:2
<option>Berkelium,2:8:18:32:27:8:2
<option>Californium,2:8:18:32:28:8:2
<option>Einsteinium,2:8:18:32:29:8:2
<option>Fermium,2:8:18:32:30:8:2
<option>Mendelevium,2:8:18:32:31:8:2
<option>Nobelium,2:8:18:32:32:8:2
<option>Lawrencium,2:8:18:32:32:8:3
<option>Rutherfordium,2:8:18:32:32:10:2
<option>Dubnium,2:8:18:32:32:11:2
<option>Seaborgium,2:8:18:32:32:12:2
<option>Bohrium,2:8:18:32:32:13:2
<option>Hassium,2:8:18:32:32:14:2
<option>Meitnerium,2:8:18:32:32:15:2
<option>Darmstadtium,2:8:18:32:32:16:2
<option>Roentgenium,2:8:18:32:32:17:2
<option>Copernicium,2:8:18:32:32:18:2
<option>Nihonium,2:8:18:32:32:18:3
<option>Flerovium,2:8:18:32:32:18:4
<option>Moscovium,2:8:18:32:32:18:5
<option>Livermorium,2:8:18:32:32:18:6
<option>Tennessine,2:8:18:32:32:18:7
<option>Oganesson,2:8:18:32:32:18:8
</select>
```

#### Working out the ideal positions

Let's take for example the orbit with 8 slots and 6 electrons to populate on it. Let's define a unit of measure such that the orbit has a circumference of 8 units (so we take a slot-to-slot distance on the circumference as unit of measure). If we for a moment forget about the slots, then a perfect distribution would be to have a distance (on the circumference) of 8 / 6 between every consecutive pair of electrons, because the sum of these 6 distances would be 8, i.e. making a full circle.

To avoid that the limited floating point precision gives us less accurate results, we could redefine the unit of measure by multiplying the numerator and denominator by 6 (the electron count), so the circumference is actually 8*6 units long, and each step is 8 (the distance between two consecutive electrons).

This is why in the loop of `shellPattern` you see the `step` variable increase with `length` (which is the number of slots in the orbit), giving us the distance (on the circumference) from the "home" position (at 0) to each electron. To translate this unit of measure back to the *original* unit of measure, we would divide by the electron count (the variable `count`). But instead of dividing, we multiply the index of the slot by `count` so we can avoid the floating point issues of a division. This product gives us the distance of the slot from the home position expressed in the new unit of measure. Every time this product passes over the current step, we should "place" the electron in the corresponding slot. This is where the rounding gets done, because we ignore the overrun of the product (the part that is more than `step`).

The `+ 0.5` is to make sure that the grid is horizontally mirrored in such a way that the home position is at the exact top. We want to "collapse" the perfect calculated position into a slot index. So we don't want the left picture, but the right picture (the shaded areas represent ranges that would collapse to the slots that are positioned at the center of them):

[image]

The difference is that additional 0.5*count which represents a half slot section. Note that 0.5 poses no problem for floating point: it has a perfect representation for 0.5

Next, we really want the slots to be filled in a way that the rounding is done symmetrically, so that the left and right side look the same. This is what the first `if` block does: whenever we have determined whether a slot is to be filled or left empty, we do exactly the same thing at the mirrored slot. If it turns out the slot number of the mirror is less than the current slot number, then we know we have "crossed" over and can stop the loop.

In case the number of electrons is *even* we *also* want the top and bottom half of the distribution to be mirrored. That is what the second `if` block does, using the same principle. In this case we only need to do one quarter of the total circumference as the rest is derived by mirroring.

Comment: Wow, so clever! Can you explain in a bit more depth how the algorithm for laying out in the "ideal" positions works?

Comment: I added an explanation. Let me know if this clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Next.js/React/SVG, so here is python.

At least the matrix indices should be correct regardless of the language.

In the code I built a square matrix representing the ascii drawing. In the matrix, 0 represents an empty ascii space; 1 represents an empty electron spot; 2 represents an actual electron. Substitute 0-> , 1->`-`, 2->`x` to get your ascii drawing.

First I wrote a function `make_layer` that builds a layer as a 1d array. For instance, you can build the third layer of manganese by calling `make_layer(3, 18, 13)` because it's layer number 3, which holds a total of 18 spots, but only 13 electrons. The logic for this function is that we can distribute k items 0..k-1 evenly among n spots 0..n-1 by placing item j at spot `floor(j * n / k)`. We do this twice: first we place k = `n_electrons` electrons among n = `layer_size` spots; then we place these k = `layer_size` spots inside a blank string of length n = `ascii_layer_size`.

Then I wrote a function `add_layer_to_matrix` that wraps a layer around inside a square matrix. This requires juggling with indices. I added a diagram below to explain visually.

And finally, function `draw_square` declares a square matrix of the appropriate size, and iterates on the layers to build them and wrap them around.

```py
data_as_string = '''Hydrogen,1
Helium,2
Lithium,2:1
Beryllium,2:2
Berkelium,2:8:18:32:27:8:2
Oganesson,2:8:18:32:32:18:8'''

data_as_dict = {row[0]: list(map(int,row[1].split(':'))) for line in data_as_string.split('\n') if len(line) >= 1 and (row:=line.strip().split(','))}
# {'Hydrogen': [1], 'Helium': [2], 'Lithium': [2, 1], 'Beryllium': [2, 2],  'Berkelium': [2, 8, 18, 32, 27, 8, 2], 'Oganesson': [2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 8]}

import numpy as np

def make_layer(radius, layer_size, n_electrons):
    square_side_length = 2 * radius + 1
    electrons_in_layer = np.ones(layer_size, dtype=int)
    electrons_in_layer[(np.arange(n_electrons) * layer_size) // n_electrons] = 2
    ascii_layer_size = (square_side_length - 1) * 4
    layer = np.zeros(ascii_layer_size, dtype=int)
    layer[(np.arange(layer_size) * ascii_layer_size) // layer_size] = electrons_in_layer
    return layer

def add_layer_to_matrix(matrix, layer, R, r):
    i = R - r
    l = 2 * r + 1
    L = 2 * R + 1
    matrix[i, R:L-1-i] = layer[:r]
    matrix[i:L-1-i, L-1-i] = layer[r:3*r]
    matrix[L-1-i, i+1:L-1-i+1] = layer[5*r-1:3*r-1:-1]
    matrix[i+1:L-1-i+1, i] = layer[7*r-1:5*r-1:-1]
    matrix[i, i:R] = layer[7*r:]

def draw_square(layer_list):
    max_radius = len(layer_list)
    square_side_length = 2 * max_radius + 1
    square_matrix = np.zeros((square_side_length, square_side_length), dtype=int)
    for (layer_size, (radius, n_electrons)) in zip((2,8,18,32,32,18,8), enumerate(layer_list, start=1)):
        layer = make_layer(radius, layer_size, n_electrons)
        add_layer_to_matrix(square_matrix, layer, max_radius, radius)
    return square_matrix

for element_name in ('Hydrogen', 'Beryllium', 'Berkelium'):
    mat = draw_square(data_as_dict[element_name])
    ascii = '\n'.join(''.join(' -x'[i] for i in row) for row in mat)
    print(element_name, data_as_dict[element_name])
    print(ascii)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Hydrogen [1]
 x 
   
 - 

Beryllium [2, 2]
- x -
  x  
-   -
  x  
- x -

Berkelium [2, 8, 18, 32, 27, 8, 2]
-      x      -
 -  -  x -  x  
  xxx- xxxx x  
 x xxxxxxxxxx- 
  xxxx xxx x-  
  xxxx x xxxxx 
 --x   x  xx   
- xxxx   xxxx -
   xx  x   xx- 
 xxxxx x xxxx  
  xx xxx xxxx  
 -xxxxxxxxxx x 
  x -xxx xxx-  
  x  - x  -  - 
-      x      -
```

The arithmetic to wrap a layer around in the matrix follows this diagram:
[image]